# I need a full list of default and custom icons and or graphics for my DXTREME project (HTML 5)

Tags: html

I'm creating a multi channel project with Visual Studio as my IDE and I'm using the DevExpress DXTREME framework which includes (dxtreme.core-12.2.js, dxtreme.framework-12.2.js, dxtreme.viz-12.2.js, dxtreme.widgets-12.2.js, globalize.js, jquery-1.2.2intellisense.js, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, knockout-2.1.0.js) for the javascript libraries. I have about four to five tabs in my task bar all labeled as (Home - Dine - Apparel - Cart - Status) and I want an icon for each corresponding word that can best describe that word. My problem is that I dont have or now all the common key words for all the default icons nor can I find them. the keywords are input into my (app.config.js) file and the ones I have so far look like this in the code

```
window.gameButlerApp1 = $.extend(true, window.gameButlerApp1, {
"config": {
    "defaultLayout": "navbar",
    "navigation": [
        {
            title: "Home",
            action: "#Index",
            icon: "home"
        },
        {
            title: "Dine",
            action: "#Menu",
            icon: "menu"
        },
        {
            title: "Apparel",
            action: "#Apparel",
            icon: "info"
        },
         {
             title: "Status",
             action: "#Order",
             icon: "info"
         },
        {
            title: "About",
            action: "#About",
            icon: "info"
        }
    ]
}
});
```

where can I find the names of the other icons i need to place in my js

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the icon-keys in the **dx.ios.default.css** file.
Search for

```
.dx-icon-
```

in it.
It is located in the css folder of your project.
(DXtreme v13.1)
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Icons are embedded as data URIs inside CSS style files for each supported device.

There are a few standard icons

```
add, plus, airplane, arrowdown, arrowleft, arrowright, arrowup, bookmark, box, car, card, cart, chart, clock, close, comment, doc, download, edit, email, event, favorites, find, folder, food, gift, globe, group, help, home, image, info, key, like, map, menu, money, music, percent, photo, preferences, product, refresh, remove, runner, tags, tel, tipcs, todo, toolbox, user, save, overflow.
```

Icons are specified in the application configuration file - (config.js)